# Why does Unix "strings" command remove XML comment close tags?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am not a Unix shell scripting expert, but I recently had a problem with a script removing the closing tag of an XML comment block, thus causing the entire file to be one huge unclosed comment, which immediately failed in the middleware system reading it. I narrowed the problem down to the `strings` command in the script.

As an example, a file, temp.xml, contains the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--
This is a comment
-->
<object>Foo</object>
```

The following command is run against it: `strings - temp.xml`

The output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--
This is a comment
<object>Foo</object>
```

Note that this behaviour is only observed when the closing comment tag is on a line of its own which contains nothing else. So `This is a comment-->` is left alone.

This seems completely nonsensical to me. Is there a reason for it?

It's happening on Linux 2.6.18. Distro is RHEL Server 5.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `strings` command only print strings of length 4 characters or more. `-->` is a length of 3 so it ignores it. Any reason you process the files with `strings`?

The man page says:

> For each file given, GNU strings prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the
>          number given with the options below) and are followed by an unprintable character.  By default, it only prints the
>          strings from the initialized and loaded sections of object files; for other types of files, it prints the strings from
>          the whole file.
>
> strings is mainly useful for determining the contents of non-text files.

Comment: The code was written by someone that's no longer with the company, so I've no idea why they chose to use `strings`. It seems to be used to remove all non-printable characters from a file in the following statement: `strings - $file|tr "\n" " " > /tmp/$file`

Comment: If it is xml I wouldn't expect it to have non printable characters.  I must admit I don't see the rationale in this case for what he was doing. Almost wonder if he meant to use `cat` instead of `strings`. The `tr` part makes sense since he is replacing all `\n' with a space. Although I wonder why he didn't  replace it with nothing.

Comment: Possibly. The files often contain French characters and others that cause problems with some downstream systems, for example some Latin ligatures (e.g. œ), en- and em-dashes, curly quotes, etc. I think the idea was to remove all of these characters.

Comment: I'd probably use `tr` to delete the non printable characters with something like `cat $file | tr -cd '\15\40-\176'` in place of `strings - $file`